# ios Should I check free disk space before downloading any file?

Tags: ios, download

My app downloads some audio files and some of them are very large.
I used to download small files without checking if free space is enough.
Should I do the check before downloading? or the system can do something for me automatically when it detects out of free space, for example, if space is not enough, the system would pop up some alvert and pause the download.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be *certain* you will be able to write the whole file, then you should write a dummy file containing random data and then overwrite it with the real data as you download it.  You can then rename the file to the correct name.

The only way the system will tell you that you don't have enough disk space is by returning `ESPACE` (in whatever form) as you attempt to write to the file, and it won't be able to pre-warn you that you have enough space for the whole file, at least not with 100% certainty.

It really depends on how important the data is, but it's very unusual to do this; I would simply attempt to write the file, report any errors and remove the half-written file on error.